# How to return value from DataStore in non-suspend function

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, android-jetpack-datastore

I was saving app language in shared preferences and set the app language by overriding `attachBaseContext()` in activity like the following:

```
    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
    
       val language: String = sharedPreferences.language

       super.attachBaseContext(wrapContext(base, language))
    }
```

where `wrapContext()` is a function change the language based on its parameter value.

after migration to DataStore, I can't return the language in `attachBaseContext()` since it's not suspend function, and language become a flow (should collect inside a suspend function)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `runBlocking` is likely to be your only option.

Answer (score 3):

DataStore is asynchronous API for writing and reading small amounts of data. [To read data synchronously](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#synchronous) you need to use `runBlocking` coroutine builder. This will block the calling thread until DataStore returns that can lead to [ANRs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr):

```
val syncData = runBlocking { context.dataStore.data.first() } // or { context.dataStore.data.firstOrNull() }
```

It is a good chance to think about how you can use DataStore asynchronously without `runBlocking`, maybe do some refactoring.

If you decide to use `runBlocking` you need to think about reasonable timeout to not freeze UI forever:

```
val syncData = runBlocking { 
    withTimeoutOrNull(2000) { // UI can freeze for 2 seconds
        context.dataStore.data.first()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can safely run blocking code on a Worker Thread by Work Manager. Or else, you can use async code with a Count Down Latch.